# Directory authentication not working

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

This is my htaccess file in the directory `/home/domain.nl/public_html/helpdesk`

```
Require user agent8 agent9 agent10 
AuthType     Basic
AuthName     this_protected_area
AuthUserFile /home/domain.nl/public_html/.htpasswd
```

But when I go to domain.nl/helpdesk I got a 324 error (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). So whats wrong? I'm sure the htpasswd file is on the correct location.

In the error logs I see this error:

```
(13)Permission denied: Couldn't read /home/domain.nl/public_html/errors/.htaccess, closing connection.
```

Comment: Well, same question as always: what do the server logs report?

Comment: (13)Permission denied: Couldn't read /home/domain.nl/public_html/errors/.htaccess, closing connection.

Comment: Do you happen to have a custom 401 page? And does it happen to sit in the `/error` directory?

Comment: No, I've searched for 401 in the htaccess files but I don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the public_html/errors/ dirrectory to errors2 and its working now. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .htaccess with this:

```
Require valid-user
AuthType     Basic
AuthName     this_protected_area
AuthUserFile /home/domain.nl/public_html/.htpasswd
```

Make sure .htaccess is enabled and if that doesn't work pls copy/paste relevant section of your error.log file in your question.

Comment: `Couldn't read /home/monteuraanhuis.nl/public_html/errors/.htaccess` means you have some custom error handler that is trying to redirect you to `/errors` and that directory either doesn't exist or isn't accessible. Can you also post relevant section of access.log.

Comment: I've checked the htaccess file in the /helpdesk directory and the root directory but there is no redirecting to the /errors directory.

Comment: Also when I check with ftp the directory content of /public_html I see the folder `errors`. But when I open it I got the message: `No such file or directory`

Comment: You can do `ls -l /home/monteuraanhuis.nl/public_html` to see what type of permissions are there on error directory and whether it is a real directory or a symbolic link.

Comment: Don't have ssh on this host. But I renamed the errors directory to errors2 and its working now. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oh good to know. Your httpd.conf might have a custom error handler redirecting you to `/errors`.